# SQLAlchemy relationships populating foreign key fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following tables with their respective sqlalchemy classes:

```
class Enrolled(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'enrolled'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    student_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('students.id'))
    student = relationship('Students', foreign_keys=[device_fk], uselist=False,backref="enrolled", innerjoin=False, post_update=False)
    subject = Column(String(5, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False)

//__init__ for id and subject is here.

class Students(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False)   
//init for name is here
```

Relationship between students and enrolled is one to many. i.e one student can enroll himself in more then 1 subject.

Now, I know to insert a couple of subjects into 'Enrolled' and names into 'Students' classes.

```
DBSession.add(Enrolled(subject="maths"))
```

In the end this is how my tables look

Enrolled:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | student_fk | subject |         
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |            | Maths   |
|  2 |            | Physics | 
|  3 |            |  Art    | 
+----+------------+---------+
```

Students:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |  
+----+------+
|  1 | Jim  | 
|  2 | Bob  |  
|  3 | Cara |  
+----+------+
```

Now, how do I get the students id get into **Enrolled** table as foreign keys?

I have this information : which student is enrolled into which subject as a .csv file..
mycsv: name,subject,name1,subject1,name2,subject2

Should I have a manual dictionary like dict {jim:maths,Bob:Art,Cara:Physics} and then map like

```
query=Enrolled(subject="maths")

for k, v in dict.items():
    if subject in v:
        list.append(k)
for i in list:
    query.student=DBSession.query(Students).filter(name=i).first()
    DBSession.add(query)
```

Please help.. How do I get the student_fk field populated properly?

Comment: Do you call `DBSession.commit()`?

Comment: No.. I didnt call that. Autocommit session is set to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1-to-many enrollment table should have composite primary key on Student ID and subject. Assuming you want to keep subjects as ENUM (which works with small list of subjects, otherwise you should move it to a separate table), you tables should look something like:

```
subjects = [ 'Maths', 'Physics', 'Art', ]

class Student(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'Student'
  student_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  name = Column(String(50, convert_unicode=True), nullable=False)

class StudentEnrollment(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'StudentEnrollment'
  student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Student.student_id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
  subject = Column(Enum(*subjects), primary_key=True)
  student = relationship("Student",   primaryjoin='StudentEnrollment.student_id==Student.student_id', uselist=True, backref="enrollments")
```

which will result in:

```
root@localhost [inDB]> show create table Student\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: Student
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [inDB]> show create table StudentEnrollment\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: StudentEnrollment
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `StudentEnrollment` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` enum('Maths','Physics','Art') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`,`subject`),
  CONSTRAINT `StudentEnrollment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `Student` (`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

then to insert few enrollments for user Jim:

```
student = Student(name='Jim')
session.add(student)
session.flush()
for enr in ('Maths', 'Physics', 'Art'):
  session.add(StudentEnrollment(student_id=student.student_id, subject=enr))     
session.flush()
session.commit()
```

which will result in:

```
root@localhost [inDB]> select * from Student;
+------------+------+
| student_id | name |
+------------+------+
|          3 | Jim  |
+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [inDB]> select * from StudentEnrollment;
+------------+---------+
| student_id | subject |
+------------+---------+
|          3 | Maths   |
|          3 | Physics |
|          3 | Art     |
+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is a very basic example with two tables. A better option would be to normalize Enrollments into separate table and use association proxy pattern, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html

Comment: Hi How do I use parent child relationship with the above?
This is given in the documentation
p = Parent()
a = Association(extra_data="some data")
a.child = Child()
p.children.append(a)

I have to add subject using append? How do I do that?